# Spring Hystrix Single Fallback with Method Arguments Not Matching

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, hystrix, circuit-breaker

I am wondering if something like the following could be implemented as I have quite a few endpoint variations and having a fallback method per endpoint with matching arguments is very messy. Alternatively a global fallback would also be fine.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest")
class SomeRestController {


   @RequestMapping(value = "/test2", method = { RequestMethod.GET})
   @HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "fallback") // FIXME Will error here because arguments do not match
   public String test2(@RequestBody String body) {
    return "Test2";
   }

   @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = { RequestMethod.GET})
   @HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "fallback")
   public String test() {
    return "Test";
   }

   public String fallback() {
    return "generic fallback"; // Return 503 and a message
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hystrix provides default method support.

You can use it in the following manner -
@HystrixCommand(defaultFallback = "fallback")